# Facebook canonical URL differing from fetched URL

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, hashbang

I'm testing my site (which uses AJAX and !#) using the facebook object debugger:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fstuff2.do%2F%3F_escaped_fragment_%3Dt%3Dactivities%26c_id%3D31

When I enter my URL to debug:
http://stuff2.do/?_escaped_fragment_=t=activities&c_id=31

The conical URL comes up as http://stuff2.do/?_escaped_fragment_=t%3Dactivities%26c_id%3D0
which is missing my last parameter's value, 31

This is causing the wrong page to be fetched.
Any ideas why this is happening anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Im no expert but it seems your id=0 which im guessing would be a default
can you change your conical url to
http://stuff2.do/?_escaped_fragment_=t%3Dactivities%26c_id%3D31

your metatags have id=0 you should change that probably in your head.
could have something to do with slugs or tags on the page maybe have a look and delete any cononical url there

hope that helps